# Finding Item ID On Terrafirmacraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, terrafirmacraft

I was wondering if there exists a list somewhere for OP give commands on `Terrafirmacraft` with item ID?

i.e.
`give pName itemID# ##`

Comment: Click F3 + H to see item ids and metadata

Comment: You would need to press F3 and H at the same time to see item IDs and Durability/Metadata. This works in any modded or vanilla minecraft version.